# MS Access executes a stored procedure differently than SSMS when querying sys tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, t-sql, sql-server-2019

I have a stored procedure that I've coded to ensure that it returns an error. The problem is that MS Access (version 2209 build 15629.20156) returns a different result in my output parameter when I query the `sys` tables. Why is this happening?

When I `INSERT` into #views with dummy data `'BLAH'`, I get the correct results.

```
SSMS result: @Status = 'ERROR'
MS Access result: @Status = 'ERROR'
```

When I `INSERT` into #views with data from `sys.objects` and `sys.sql_modules`, Access returns the wrong result.

```
SSMS result: @Status = 'ERROR'
MS Access result: @Status = 'OK'
```

This is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.TestSP 
    @Status nvarchar(255) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#views') IS NOT NULL
       DROP TABLE #views

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#GSSTables') IS NOT NULL
       DROP TABLE #GSSTables

    CREATE TABLE #views (objectName nvarchar(100))
    CREATE TABLE #GSSTables (objectName nvarchar(100))

    SET @Status = 'OK'

    INSERT INTO #views (objectName)
        SELECT --This makes @Status return 'OK' in Access
            a.name
        FROM
            sys.objects a WITH (NOLOCK)
        INNER JOIN
            sys.sql_modules b WITH (NOLOCK) ON a.object_id = b.object_id
        WHERE
            a.type = 'V'
            AND b.definition LIKE '%OPENQUERY(GSS%,%'

        --select --This makes @Status return 'ERROR' in Access

        --  'BLAH' 
    
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM #views v 
               LEFT JOIN #GSSTables g ON v.objectName = g.objectName 
               WHERE g.objectName IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        SET @Status = 'ERROR'
        RETURN
    END

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#views') IS NOT NULL
       DROP TABLE #views

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#GSSTables') IS NOT NULL
       DROP TABLE #GSSTables
END
```

The VB code (runs off a button press):

```
   Dim con As ADODB.Connection, cmd As New ADODB.Command, prm As New ADODB.Parameter
   Dim Status As String
   
   If Not EstablishConnection(con) Then
      ErrHandler glbLastErrNum, glbLastError
      GoTo ExitLabel
   End If

   Set cmd.ActiveConnection = con
   cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
   cmd.CommandText = "TestSP"

   Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("@Status", adVarChar, adParamOutput, 255)
   cmd.Parameters.Append prm

   cmd.Execute

   Status = cmd.Parameters("@Status")
   MsgBox Status
```

Comment: Probably it runs as different users so you have different permissions to see things

Comment: Or a different database or server?

Comment: Probably, you run test in SSMS with <test db>, and run test from Access with connection to <other db>. Perhaps, in <other db> is nothing ``b.definition LIKE '%OPENQUERY(GSS%,%'`` and procedure result is Ok. In <test db>, you have "desirable" object and got result Error.